# UINavigationBar Color Change and Shadow Removal Without Subclassing?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationbar

I want to change the color of UINavigationBar to a solid color of my choice. in IB I added a solid color to Background and Tint properties. However, there is a shadow right under the bar. How can I remove it without subclassing the UINavigationBar? If not, then how to subclass it?

Comment: Did you get any solution to remove the shadow of UINavigationBar ?

Comment: Not yet. Still looking.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up subclassing UINavigationBar like so:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyNavigationBar : UINavigationBar <UINavigationBarDelegate> {

}

@end
```

And within .M file I overwrote this

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
 UIColor * color = [UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0f green:255/255.0f blue:255/255.0f alpha:1.0f];
 CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
 CGContextSetFillColor(context, CGColorGetComponents( [color CGColor]));
 CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
}
```

Note: I could not use [UIColor whiteColor] for some reason - it was defaulting to black so I ended up using colorWithRed:green:blue: instead.

It worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the UINavigationBar's shadowImage to [[UIImage alloc] init] to remove the shadow. This will only work on iOS 5.0+ though.